# Return an INT from a Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am attempting to create a row called Flag that will keep a count of when Value is above 2. Later I will need to sum flag as a count.

I currently have:

```
CASE 
WHEN Value > 2
    THEN  1
ELSE  0
END AS 'Flag',

CASE 
    WHEN 'Flag' = 1  
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS 'FollowedUpCorrectly'
```

I receive the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Flag' to data
>   type int.

How can I force the 1 or 0 to be an INT in order to do later math?

I've looked around and I can't seem to find a way that fits.

Comment: Write query in detail

Comment: Why can't you just do `CASE When Value > 2 Then 1 Else 0 End As FollowedUpCorrectly`?

Comment: here **Flag** is a varchar value, compare **[Flag]=1**  for column comparison

Comment: @Siyual the Then and Else in  FollowedUpCorrectly are currently placeholders where more logic will go.

Comment: So the problem was in this case that 'Flag' is reading the varchar not the column. That was a simple mistake. I had previously tried it without the quotes and it said 'Flag' was an invalid column name.

It seems the overall problem was what some people had suggested being that the second case couldn't see the first. Outer apply fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use previously created columns in the select, you'll need to use for example outer apply, with something like this:

```
select
  *
from table1
outer apply (
  select CASE WHEN Value > 2 THEN  1 ELSE 0 END AS Flag
) X
outer apply (
  select CASE WHEN X.Flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FollowedUpCorrectly
) Y
```

Test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3db68/1)

Comment: This outer apply was what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand what you are after.

```
CASE 
WHEN Value > 2
    THEN  1
ELSE  0
END AS 'Flag',

CASE 
    WHEN 'Flag' = 1  
        THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS 'FollowedUpCorrectly'
```

If these two lines are in the same code block, `'Flag'` is unknown in the second **Case Statement**.

Update: As Siyual has pointed out, `Flag` is a string literal. Try changing the name to something that is not a reserved word.

Comment: Technically, `'Flag'` is known, because `'Flag'` is a string literal.  And you can't compare that to the integer 1.  But there are multiple problems with this query.

Comment: Thanks @Siyual - I updated the answer to include your added information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CTE or a subquery to create a flag and then do your case statement as needed in the outer query like this:

```
;WITH q1
AS (
    SELECT 
         col1
        ,col2
        ,col3
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Value > 2
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END AS 'Flag'
    FROM your_table --change this to match your table and column name
    )
SELECT q1.col1
      ,q1.col2
      ,q1.col3
      ,CASE 
        WHEN q1.Flag = 1
                THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END AS 'FollowedUpCorrectly'
FROM q1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string ('Flag') to an int (1).  Perhaps you meant to refer to the first case that you named 'Flag'.   If so, try referring to it without using the single quotes. Then the analyzer will recognize it and accept it as an int, which it is.   But 'Flag' is a string.   Flag is an int.